# How do i automatically send an email after user submit their email address in the newsletter form?

Tags: php, html, email

I want to automatically send an email that says "thank you for signing up for our newsletter form. If you have any questions please email kundeservice@.....no

I have tried multiple different codes that I tried to change but nothing has worked. I need to use `the $_GET['epost']` so I send it correctly to the email.

I am not sure if I need to install something on the terminal. Currently using `ubuntu 18.04`

**HTML:**

```
<form name="form" class="forms" action="/backup/formsend.php" id="formn" method="post" >
    <div class="email">
        <input type="text" name="epost" id="epost" placeholder="E-Post" required>
    </div>

    <div class="submitknapp">
        <input class="knapp" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST['epost'];
    $email_subject = "News letter";
    $email_content = "thank you for signing up for our newsletter form. If you have any questions please email kundeservice@.....no";
    mail($email,$email_subject,$email_content);
?>
```

mail() function is used to send email to mentioned email address.